# Оптимизация счётчика онлайн

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый вечер. Существует MYSQL таблица `users`, в которой есть поля `id | login | lastdate`.

1. `ID` - Уникальный порядковый номер.
2. `Login` - никнейм пользователя (не уникальный).
3. `Lastdate` - время последнего обращения пользователя к сайту (TIMESTAMP).

Таблица `Users` содержит около 400 тысяч записей. При запросе

```
"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `lastdate`>'{$lastdate}'";
```

`$lastdate` = временной порог, при котором пользователь считается как онлайн. Итак, при такой запросе тратится очень много времени. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно оптимизировать этот запрос, либо дайте другие рекомендации, которые помогут сэкономить время.

Comment: А lastdate является ключевым?
Кэшируйте.

Comment: index есть на lastdate ?
В phaMyAdmin експортируйте структуру таблицы и сюда выложите.

Comment: index не стоит

Comment: Так поставьте! :)

Надеюсь, что только индекс не стоит ;-)

Comment: В каком формате записываете lastdate?

Comment: Ещё как вариант можно добавить поле к примеру is_online и скриптом по cron'у к примеру каждые 10 мин (насколько важна точность) устанавливать 1 или 0. И индекс на это поле добавить.

Comment: Непонятен смысл запроса. Вряд ли это желание посмотреть, кто онлайн, скорее, полученный список далее используется в какой-то операции. А коли так - то, может, нужно посмотреть на всё в комплексе? Например, мне кажется, что это - таблица регистраций просмотров. Так почему бы не создать ещё одну таблицу - последних обращений (она будет гораздо компактнее). обновляемую триггером AFTER INSERT первой таблицы? выборка из неё будет намного быстрее.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте индекс к полю lastdate.
Еще можно начать использовать MemCache. Он еще больше сокращает временные затраты на выполнение запроса к базам данных.